# xslt count following records

Tags: batch-file, xslt, count

Using XSLT 1.0, I need to write Count of Txn records that "follow" the SegmentHeader. The number of Txn records I can write under each SegmentHeader is restricted. For example - If I have a total of 5 transaction records with a restriction of 3 per segment, they should be separated into 2 SegmentHeaders, holding 3 and 2 transaction records.

Required Output:

```
<file>
    <SegmentHeader>
        <TransactionCount>3</TransactionCount>
    </SegmentHeader>
    <Txn />
    <Txn />
    <Txn />
    <SegmentHeader>
        <TransactionCount>2</TransactionCount>
    </SegmentHeader>
    <Txn />
    <Txn />
</file>
```

By using "position() mod $recordLimit = 1" I am able to write both SegmentHeaders and Txn records as needed, but could not figure out a way to write the transaction count.

Comment: There's not enough information here. Please provide a sample of the _input_ XML for which the output is shown, and include your current efforts at writing the XSLT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple example you could adapt to your situation:

**XML**

```
<input>
    <item>a</item>
    <item>b</item>
    <item>c</item>
    <item>d</item>
    <item>e</item>
</input>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="group-size" select="3"/>

<xsl:template match="/input">
    <output>
        <xsl:for-each select="item[position() mod $group-size = 1]">
            <xsl:variable name="group"  select=". | following-sibling::item[position() &lt; $group-size]"/>
            <header>
                <item-count>
                    <xsl:value-of select="count($group)"/>
                </item-count>
            </header>
            <xsl:copy-of select="$group"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </output>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<output>
   <header>
      <item-count>3</item-count>
   </header>
   <item>a</item>
   <item>b</item>
   <item>c</item>
   <header>
      <item-count>2</item-count>
   </header>
   <item>d</item>
   <item>e</item>
</output>
```